# Custom Select() with parameter

Tags: select, ngxs

### UPDATE

As of @NGXS v3.1, they finally introduced arguments into @Selector().

https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#lazy-selectors

## Examples from the DOCS

First, you define the @Selector "**pandas**"

```
@State<string[]>({
  name: 'animals',
  defaults: []
})

@Injectable()
export class ZooState {
  @Selector()
  static pandas(state: string[]) {
    return (type: string) => {
      return state.filter(s => s.indexOf('panda') > -1).filter(s => s.indexOf(type) > -1);
    };
  }
}
```

Then you just call it in your '.ts' file

```
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({ ... })
export class ZooComponent {
  babyPandas$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.babyPandas$ = this.store
      .select(ZooState.pandas)
      .pipe(map(filterFn => filterFn('baby')));
  }
}
```

---

*** From Old Post ***

I am trying to create a custom @Select () to be able to drill down a particular tree and return the values dynamically. Getting either undefined or it's not making it (executing)

user.component.ts

```
const location = 'new york'
@Select(state => UserState.getUserLocationSlots(state, location)) slots$;
```

user.state.ts

```
@Selector() 
static getUserLocationSlots(state: UserStateModel, location: any) {
  console.log(state);
  console.log(location); // <-- expecting 'new york', but getting undefined
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to pass parameter to `@Selector()` decorated functions in ngxs v2. It would be nice though.

A ticket exist for this [feature request](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/195).

Also, I think you are not using @Selector() correctly. I should be something like (hence, cannot pass parameters):

```
@Select(UserState.getUserLocationSlots) slots$
```

Refer to the [docs](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#memoized-selectors).

Note: I am not an expert in ngxs...this is just based on what I understand now.

Comment: Frankly, anything help. Thanks. Going to try the following 
`@Select(state => state.user['location'].slots) user$;`

Comment: Yup, didn't work. I'll keep looking and post a reply if I can ever get it to work

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve this by using `crateSelector` function from `@ngxs/store`

In your .state.ts file:

```
static getLocationSlots(location: string) {
    return createSelector([UserState], (state: string[) => {
        // logic for filtering your data
        // eg.: state.filter(element => element == location)
    })
}

In your .component.ts file:

@Select(UserState.getLocationSlots('new york')) slots$: Observable<any>
```

> You can also check [here](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select) for more details

Comment: What about if the @Select() is in an injectable Service and from the component you want to send the 'new york' as param? Is there a nice way for this?

Answer (score 4):

To pass parameters you can have the select return a function, it isn't elegant, however it works.

For example the select statement would look like:

```
  @Selector()
  static getItemByIdFn(state: { [id: number]: Entity }) {
    return (id: number) => {
      return state[id];
    };
  }
```

then in the component:

```
this.store.select(MyState.getItemByIdFn)
  .pipe(map(mapByIdFn) => mayByIdFn(1)) // using the returned function
  .subscribe(...);
```

Note the map, which is where you pass your id to the returned function. Here you can place whatever parameters you would like.

Hope this helps :)!

Answer (score 3):

This is achievable in NGXS v2 & v3. Copied from my comment in the discussion on dynamic selectors [here](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/386#issuecomment-390181710)

> We can achieve this at the moment using a pattern often used for redux
>   selectors...
>
> The `@Selector` decorator can be written so that it returns a function
>   with the desired parameter. This enables the desired dynamic selector
>   arguments as well as late resolution of the selected state. For
>   Example:
>
> ```
> @State<UserStateModel>( ... ) 
> export class UserState {   
>   @Selector()  
>   getFilteredUsersFn(userStateModel: UserStateModel) {
>     return (filter: string) => 
>       userStateModel.users.filter((user) => user.indexOf(filter) >= 0);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> And then the component would contain:
>
> ```
> @Component({...}) 
> export class AppComponent {  
>   @Select(UserState.getFilteredUsersFn) 
>   filteredUsersFn$: Observable<(filter: string) => User[]>;
>
>   get currentFilteredUsers$() {
>     return this.filteredUsersFn$
>       .pipe(map(filterFn => filterFn('myFilter')));   
>   } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, Mark, giving this a shot.